# Возникла ошибка с json searilize

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Код ошибки:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'country.id', line 1, position 288."
```

Мой код:

```
Country countryjs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Country>(abc);
Console.WriteLine(countryjs.Name.ToString());
```

Класс:

```
public partial class Country
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("urlName")]
    public string UrlName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("region", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public long? Region { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public long? CountryCountry { get; set; }
}
```

country:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: похоже что ваш JSON не валиден строковые значения должны быть в кавычках а у вас ОАЭ и UAE без кавычек

Comment: Да,почти. Увы  мне просто не приходил этот кусок json